# Retrieving an item from a List results in a com.sun.jdi.InvocationException error

Tags: java, oracle, list, nullpointerexception

I am using the [Oracle Test Manager API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97999_01/OTMUG/otmappa.htm#CHDFGDFC) to write a class to retrieve some information from the system. The object I am working with has a method getTestCases() that returns a list of objects. The size of the list returned is 1. However, if I attempt to call any method on the list, like get(), or even print it I get a NullPointerException.

```
    AssociationList<TestCase> tc = r.getTestCases();
    //this prints 1
    System.out.println("tc size " + tc.size());
    //this throws a NullPointerException
    System.out.println("tc item " + tc);
```

Shouldn't the last print statement at least print out the hashcode? What would cause a NullPointer?
I made a break point at that line. Inspecting the object reveals a "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method".

If the list contains an item, why would a list behave this way? Can it be an issue with the Oracle implementation of the API?

Screenshot of debugger
[image: debugger]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You must initialize an asset path for TestCase to be able to retrieve TestCases from Requirement

I added the following and it worked

```
TestCase tcRoot = (TestCase) otm.resolve("Test Cases/");
```